# Стоит ли упоминать в программе А, которая использует программу Б по MIT лицензии, программу В, которую использует программа Б?

Tags: лицензирование, авторские-права

Допустим есть программа(библиотека) "Жираф" под MIT лицензией (или какой-либо другой) в которой используется другая программа "Белка" тоже под MIT лицензией. Например структура может быть такой.

```
# MIT Лицензия вашей программы (Жираф)

Код вашей программы

...

    # Участок чужого кода с MIT лицензией (Белка)

    # MIT Лицензия чужой программы

    Код чужой программы

...

Код вашей программы

Конец программы
```

И так как MIT лицензия требует, чтобы о ней упоминалось при использовании чужого кода, то отсюда
возникает такой вопрос.

Допустим вашу программу "Жираф" будет некто использовать в своей программе "Зоопарк", и по правилам MIT лицензии он обязан упомянуть о ней в своей программе. А как насчёт MIT лицензии чужой программы "Белка", которая используется в "Жирафе", о ней тоже необходимо упоминать, так как код
"Белка" всё же используется в "Зоопарке" при посредничестве "Жирафа" или достаточно будет ограничиться упоминанием лицензии для "Жирафа"?

Comment: Ну так упомяните, Вам от этого хуже не будет, а условия лицензии точно будут выполнены. В любом случае, можно написать разработчику "Жирафа" и спросить его, как он думает.

Comment: Как вариант, но не во всех проектах есть список лицензий в одном месте.